# How do I fix these parameters for HTTPBODY in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have;

```
let parameters =
        [
          "generalSearchInput": search,
          "requireAllWords": true,
          "brandOwner": brand,
          "includeDataTypes":
          {
              "Branded": true
          }
        ] as [String : Any]
```

THE ABOVE OBVIOUSLY DOES NOT WORK, I just do not understand how to do nested.

I am trying to mimic;

```
{
    "generalSearchInput": "SHARP CHEDDAR CHEESE",
    "requireAllWords": true,
    "brandOwner": "usa",
    "includeDataTypes": 
    {
        "Branded": true
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just use `[ ]` instead of `{ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let parameters: [String : Any] =
    [
      "generalSearchInput": search,
      "requireAllWords": true,
      "brandOwner": brand,
      "includeDataTypes":
      [
          "Branded": true
      ]
    ]
```

> In swift dictionary composing a json dictionary is expressed with [:] and array with [ ]

Comment: yes but ill still accept your answer when it allows me too!

Comment: dictionary and array both are expressed with [ ]. The difference between both is ":". So dictionary will be  [ : ] and array will be [ ]

Answer (score 0):

In swift language...

**Dictionary is declared in following way.**

```
let dict = ["name": "Mahendra", "phno": "9876543210"]
```

OR

```
let dict: [AnyHashable: String] = ["name": "Mahendra", "phno": "9876543210"]
```

**Array is declared in following way.**

```
let array = ["Mahendra", "Sachin"]
```

OR

```
let array: [String] = ["Mahendra", "Sachin"]
```

So in your case you need declare `parameters` dictionary in following way...

```
let parameters: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
  "generalSearchInput": search,
  "requireAllWords": true,
  "brandOwner": brand,
  "includeDataTypes": [
      "Branded": true
  ]
]
```

> Here you have to specify the (Key, Value) pair type as your dictionary contains heterogeneous values.